# Is there a difference between NetID and Network Address?

Tags: cisco, network, packet-tracer

So i know the gist of it. Thanks to the help here

Network Address i see as anything ending with 0
Example: 192.168.0.0

Broadcast Address i see as anything ending with 255
Example: 192.168.0.255

Whereas NetID i honestly just see in theory as what your network is identified as, example 192.168.0.X

But let me know if i am wrong. Just curious?

Comment: Network addresses most certainly don't have to end with .0 and not every address ending with .0 is a network address. The same goes for broadcast addresses on 255. Please see the answers to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers) for a much more detailed explanation.

Comment: Your assumptions are too simple and often not correct. See [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers) for a discussion on how IP addresses, subnetting, masks and prefixes work.

Comment: "all-zeros" and "all-ones" addresses. Networks do not always land perfectly on /8, /16, and /24 boundaries. (and haven't had to for many DECADES.)

Answer (score 3):

Your "gist" is wrong, unfortunately. "0"s and "255"s may or may not indicate anything.

The important thing to remember is that IP addresses are 32-bit binary numbers.  The dotted-decimal notation (1.2.3.4) is just there to make it easier for humans to read.  The dots have no meaning.

So the *network address* depends on the subnet mask.  You can't assume it ends in zero. Same for the broadcast address -- it depends on the subnet mask.

The term *Netid* is not well-defined.  We would have to see the term in context to tell you for sure if is the same thing as *network address*.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the titular question... "Network Address" is a well defined term. (in many RFC's) NetID is not.

The *Network Address* is the **all-zeros** address of a subnet. For a /24, that's a dot-zero. For a /25 [0xxxxxxx & 1xxxxxxx], that's a dot-zero and dot-128. *Broadcast* is the **all-ones** address. (127 and 255 for the aforementioned /25)

Answer (score 1):

> Network Address i see as anything ending with 0 Example: 192.168.0.0

Not correct. A network address or *prefix* is anything where the host bits are all `0`. Your example works for /24 only.

With e.g. a /26 subnet, the network address could end with .0, .64, .128, or .192.

A /23 could end with any even number in the third octet and 0 in the fourth.

> Broadcast Address i see as anything ending with 255 Example: 192.168.0.255

The subnet directed broadcast address is the network address with all host bits `1`. Same logic as above applies (.255 only for a /24, /26 with .63, .127, .191, .255, and so on).

In a nutshell: without knowing the subnet mask, you can't tell whether an address is a prefix or a directed broadcast. E.g. 192.168.0.255 is *not* the broadcast address for 192.168.0.0/23.